# Magento 2 - Add custom sort by option in cattegory page and make it default

Tags: magento2, plugin, development, category-listing, sort

I have added custom sort by option "random" for category page. I have used following code to add random option:

I have used plugin .

> app/code/DL/CustomSortOption/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
    <plugin name="sortby_add_custom_option" type="DL\CustomSortOption\Plugin\Model\Config" />
</type>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
    <plugin name="sortby_extend_default_sort_filters" type="DL\CustomSortOption\Plugin\Block\Toolbar" />
</type>
```

> app/code/DL/CustomSortOption/Plugin/Model/Config:

```
<?php
    namespace DL\CustomSortOption\Plugin\Model;

    class Config
    {
        public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
        {
          $customOption['random'] = __('Random');
          $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);
          return $options;
        }

    }
?>
```

> app/code/DL/CustomSortOption/Plugin/Block/Toolbar

```
<?php
namespace DL\CustomSortOption\Plugin\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;

 class Toolbar
 {
     protected $_collection;

     public function aroundSetCollection(
         \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
         \Closure $proceed,
         $collection
     ) {
         $this->_collection = $collection;
         $currentOrder = $toolbar->getCurrentOrder();
         $currentDirection = $toolbar->getCurrentDirection();
         $result = $proceed($collection);

         if ($currentOrder) {
             switch ($currentOrder) {
               case 'random':
                   $this->_collection
                       ->getSelect()
                       ->order('RAND()');
               break;

               default:
                   $this->_collection
                       ->setOrder($currentOrder, $currentDirection);
               break;
             }
         }
         //var_dump((string) $this->_collection->getSelect()); You can use this to get a list of all the available sort fields
         return $result;
     }


 }
?>
```

This new option Random which I added is working fine and appears in sort by drop-down in front-end on category page. I want this new option to be made default so when user opens category page it should be applied by default.

}

Comment: For this, you need to create plugin for the category product collection function and set the filter there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a plugin method before the `setDefaultOrder($field)` method in the toolbar Block. For example the following short method should do it (add it into `app/code/DL/CustomSortOption/Plugin/Block/Toolbar` and configure it in `di.xml`):

```
public function beforeSetDefaultOrder(
                \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar, 
                 $field)
{
  //if the 'random' is not set as sort order at this moment, 
  //you need to add it like below with addOrderToAvailableOrders
  //$toolbar->addOrderToAvailableOrders('random', 'random');

  //set the input parameter to 'random'
  return ['random'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks HelgeB. It is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Great to here that. Tt would be good if you accept the answer if it was helpful, in this way others can better take profit of it if they have similar problems